# How to handle Spam Deleting in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mbox

I have a list of items that each have a trash can beside them(ie delete button). Since there are so many possible results I display 25 results and then page the rest(when a user clicks the next page button at this time I get the next results).

However the problem that I am facing is once they delete a item, if there are still items in the database I want to retrieve their next item.

So 30 items belong to this user, they see 25 and if they delete one, the next item(item 26) gets pulled from the database and shown.

I don't think this would be hard to achieve the problem happens if they want to delete 5 items and click each after each other, I am scared a race condition will happen and instead of pulling item26, item27,item28,item29,item30, it may pull item26 x 5.

The only idea I can come up with is that I pull more than I show, if I show 25 records I pull 35 records and then keep refilling that bucket after each one gets deleted.

However I not sure how I would replenish the bucket of extras and scenarios on how to handle if there is not enough items to replenish the bucket.

I am using Reactjs, Mobx and Mobx State Tree.

I don't have any code yet as I no clue which way to go yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I Would do:

1. Create an array within the state to hold currently deleting items
2. Within my delete function Check if the item is currently being deleted
3. If is being deleted do nothing
4. If is not, add the item to the array, call axios.delete() and then remove the item from the array

```js
class PreventSpam extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    //Example data
    const exampleList = [{id: 1, name: "One"},
                         {id: 2, name: "Two"},
                         {id: 3, name: "Three"},
                         {id: 4, name: "Four"}]
    //State of the current component
    this.state={
      Deleting: [],
      items: exampleList
    }
    
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    this.loadNext = this.loadNext.bind(this);
  }
  
  deleteItem(item){
     //Remove element from my state
     let newItems = this.state.items.filter(it=> it.id !== item.id);
     this.setState({
       items: newItems
     });
     
     //If this items is currently being deleted, return;
     if(this.state.Deleting.indexOf(item.id) !== -1){
       console.log("wait for this deletion to complete")
       return;
     }
     
     //Add the item to the deleting array
     this.setState((state,props)=> ({
       Deleting: [...state.Deleting, item.id]
     }));
     
     //call delete with axios
     axios.delete(`url/${item.id}`).then(()=>{
        //Delete successful, update the deleting list
          let newDeleting = [...this.state.Deleting];
          let deletedIndex = newDeleting.indexOf(item.id);
          newDeleting.splice(deletedIndex, 1);
          this.setState({Deleting: newDeleting});
       
          
          //Load next item
       loadNext();
     }).catch(error => {
        //Opt 1: add the item back to the state on error
          //Opt 2: alert the user
          //Opt 3: ?????
     })
  }
  
  //Loads the 25th or last item on the database
  loadNext(){
    axios.get("apiCall").then(response => {
      let newItem = response.data;
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {items} = this.state;
    return (<div>
      <table>
         <tbody>
           {items.map((item,index)=>{
             return (
               <tr key={index}>
                 <td>{item.id}</td>
                 <td>{item.name}</td>
                 <td><button onClick={() => this.deleteItem(item)}>Delete</button></td>
               </tr>
             )
            })
           }
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PreventSpam  />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I not 100% following. So you add them to the array of items to delete, but when does the actually axios get called to be deleted? Is this once they stop deleting?

Comment: Added a snippet. Basically the array is used to stop multiple calls to the same deleted item, axios is called when the button is clicked, if is not being deleted already.

Comment: Ah, yea I was not really concerned about deleting the same item twice though this is a valid concern as I was thinking that it would get deleted always what is not the case. My original concern is LoadNext() what happens if I quickly go and try to delete 5 items at once, How do I get the correct next 5 items back and not the same next item coming back 5 times as I am pretty much in a race condition.

Comment: You could:
***Limit the delete calls to only one item at a time  preventing multiple loads of the same items (Which could be frustrating to the user).
***On the LoadNext() after you get the result, compare to your current list of loaded items, if it already exists, call LoadNext() again.

Comment: Yea, that thought crossed my mind, but I would think it would be frustrating to the user. Your second way could work though it could lead to multiple calls. Maybe it would be rare but they click fast and 5 of the same items come back then 4 of them are duplicates so the other 4 fire off which potentially could bring back 4 duplicates then 1 makes it through and were down to 3 and it goes down to 1. So in the end like 20 calls are called to get 5 new items.

Comment: Then, your options are:
***Using Throttling or Debouncing (https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).
***Creating a queue for your requests, housecall could help you with that (https://github.com/bitkompagniet/housecall).